# Getting TypeError on angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS and I am getting an error I don't entirely understand. On this block of code I get a type error (listed below). The error points me to the line with sprint.users which is an array of users.

```
$scope.countThisUserSprintsCompleted = function (user) {
    var thisUserTotalSprintsCompleted = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.sprints, function(sprint) {
        angular.forEach(sprint.users, function (sprintUser, index) {

            if(sprintUser.username == user.username && sprint.status == 'complete') {
                thisUserTotalSprintsCompleted++;
            }
        });
    });
    return thisUserTotalSprintsCompleted;
};



angular.js:13642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
at userController.js:2123
at Object.q [as forEach] (angular.js:336)
at m.$scope.countThisUserSprintsCompleted (userController.js:2122)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14539), <anonymous>:4:357)
at m.$digest (angular.js:17211)
at angular.js:17417
at e (angular.js:5912)
at angular.js:6191
```

Comment: It means, with the code provided, that `sprint` is undefined.

Comment: Not that fast @guys up, look at the line above

Comment: @Damiano you can put whatever you want as param, doesn't mean they'll be defined when called.

Comment: Right, so you should probably check $scope.sprints (console.log($scope.sprints)) and look up for undefined and null values

Comment: We would need to see all the code that modifies `$scope.sprints` to help pinpoint the issue, but this is something you should be able to track down with a little local debugging.

Comment: There is some problem with the sprint variable....can you provide this json

Comment: I ended up finding the error. I was reading $scope.sprints before the data was being read from the firebase database.

Comment: Ohh...so is your problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

It means, with the code provided, that `sprint` is undefined.

Since you're supposed to be getting `sprint` in the `angular.forEach` callback, it's probably an `undefined` value inside `$scope.sprints`.

As an example:

```js
[1, undefined, 2].forEach(function(value){
    console.log(value); 
});
```

To fix this (more of a patch), you could add a check before using `sprint`:

```js
[{ test: "value" }, undefined, { test: "other value" }].forEach(function(value){
  if (value) console.log(value.test); 
});
```

If you're not expecting `undefined` value at that point, you should investigate `$scope.sprints` before entering the `forEach` and try to fix the problem there.

Comment: I checked using the console.log() and no null values. I am using firebase for data and I think my problem is that I create the $scope.sprints before it is reading the data from the firebase DB.

Comment: thanks for the help though, going back to debug helped me find it.

Comment: @tvandezande The best way to thank someone on SO is with an upvote!